# Google maps appcache but NOT offline

Tags: google-maps, html5-appcache

i am building a mobile web app (html5, javascript)
and i use application cache of html5 for offline capabilities.
I have a problem with google maps. I cache all the files i need,
and i run my app from application cache. But when i try to use google maps 
api 3 everything goes wrong (keep in mind i have internet connection,
i do not want to use google maps offline). I do not know what to 
include in the manifest file to make the app get the files needed from
the internet. What do i have to include in the manifest file so the 
GET request of google maps api 3 not to fail.

Thank you all for the responses.

Alkis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now use:

```
NETWORK
*
```

This means all resources not cached will require a connection.

Comment: I'm changing the the answer to yours. Since then something changed and my answer no longer works. Upvoted and accepted.